# Changing default link handler in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome

I'm tying "http://google.com" into the Run prompt, click OK, and nothing happens. How do I edit the default program that handles links?

I'm using Chrome, and when I browse at its settings it is marked as the default program to handle links. Should I reinstall Chrome to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Windows 7's own settings?

If you go to start there should be an option for Standard programs (below Configuration screen), there you can set Chrome to your default browser. Worked for me.

[Check this link for more information](http://www.nirmaltv.com/2009/01/31/how-to-set-up-default-programs-in-windows-7/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I saw both "Google.Chrome" and "Google.Chrome.ron" (my username), and changed the associations to Google.Chrome.ron